# Why hot soup is tastier than cold soup?

Tags: temperature, physical-chemistry, biology, perception, food

My physics teacher recently asked me this question. Can anyone answer the question?

Comment: How do you measure "taste"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn’t about physics.

Comment: Assumes facts not in evidence.  There are [soups you eat cold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gazpacho).

Comment: @JonCuster Agreed. Probably a better fit for biology.se?

Comment: @ApoorvKhurasia - More likely Seasoned Advice (yes, SE has a cooking channel).

Comment: It is a bizzarre question likely to ask about volatiles in it. A too warm soup doesn't taste more than a cold one. Often is the opposite.

Comment: Hot soup moves around more

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Hot soup should cover more surface area of the person's tongue than cold soup due to decreased surface tension. This in term means that more taste receptors would get the sensation when the soup is hot than when it is cold. I guess that covering more taste receptors somehow makes the brain interpret the soup as tastier.